# generate XML from a dynamic dataset

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-3.0

I have an ASP.net application in c#  where I have a dataset which I can transfer to xml by using the following simple codeblock:

```
string result;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
ds.WriteXml(sw);
result = sw.ToString();
}
```

Which generates an xml block like the following:

```
<NewDataSet>
<ImageInfo>
<ImageID>1</ImageID>
<ImageName>untitled.bmp</ImageName>
<ImagePath>Some Path</ImagePath>
<Width>800</Width>
<Height>190</Height>
<TileSize>256</TileSize>
<Overlap>1</Overlap>
<MimeType>image/jpeg</MimeType>
<Scale />
</ImageInfo>
</NewDataSet>
```

This is obviously an example of one row, there are multiple rows in the dataset. Now, I dont know how to format a XML block dynamically. 
Can anyone point me to some good tutorials on this?
I want the XML to be formatted like the following

```
<data>
<Columns>
<Column Name= "ImageID"/>
<Column Name= "ImageName"/>
<Column Name= "ImagePath"/>
<Column Name= "Width"/>
<Column Name= "Height"/>
<Column Name= "TileSize"/>
<Column Name= "Overlap"/>
<Column Name= "MimeType"/>
<Column Name= "Scale"/>
</Columns>
<Rows>
<Row>
<Cell>1</Cell>
<Cell>untitled.bmp</Cell>
<Cell>Some Path</Cell>
<Cell>800</Cell>
<Cell>190</Cell>
<Cell>256</Cell>
<Cell>1</Cell>
<Cell>image/jpeg</Cell>
<Cell></Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
.
.
.
</Row>
</Rows>
</data>
```

**Can anyone guide me how to do this?**

In my application, **I wont be knowing the structure of the dataset beforehand.** i.e. there can be a resulting dataset where I have more columns than the ones described in the example. How should I go about this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DataTable and then convert that DataTable to an XML stream or a file.

```
DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];


myDataTable.WriteXml(..);
```

You will find whole bunch of overloads like TextWriter, Stream. Finally you need to modify that xml to add the nodes besides that DataTable.

Comment: thanks for replying. But that is not what I am asking. I mentioned I can get the first xml block from the dataset. I want to know, like you said, how to modify that xml to add nodes to make it look like the second xml block in the question. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a work around. The code standard can be better but for now you can use the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument Outputdoc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<NewDataSet> <ImageInfo> <ImageID>1</ImageID> <ImageName>untitled.bmp</ImageName> <ImagePath>Some Path</ImagePath> <Width>800</Width> <Height>190</Height> <TileSize>256</TileSize> <Overlap>1</Overlap> <MimeType>image/jpeg</MimeType> <Scale /> <ImageID>1</ImageID> <ImageName>untitled.bmp</ImageName> <ImagePath>Some Path</ImagePath> <Width>800</Width> <Height>190</Height> <TileSize>256</TileSize> <Overlap>1</Overlap> <MimeType>image/jpeg</MimeType> <Scale /></ImageInfo> </NewDataSet> ");
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/NewDataSet/ImageInfo");
        XmlNodeList nodes = node.ChildNodes;
        XmlDocument newdoc = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<data><Columns>");
        string lastNode=string.Empty;
        string firstNode = string.Empty;
        foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if(n.Name.Equals(firstNode))
                break;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstNode))
                firstNode = n.Name;

            newdoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode newNode = newdoc.CreateElement("Column");
            XmlAttribute newAttribute = newdoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
            newAttribute.Value = n.Name;
            newNode.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
            newdoc.AppendChild(newNode);
            sb.Append(newdoc.InnerXml);
            lastNode=n.Name;
        }
        sb.Append("</Columns><Rows><Row>");
        foreach (XmlNode xnode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            XmlDocument newdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode newNode = newdoc1.CreateElement("Cell");
            newNode.InnerText = xnode.InnerText;
            newdoc1.AppendChild(newNode);
            sb.Append(newdoc1.InnerXml);
            if (xnode.Name.Equals(lastNode))
                sb.Append("</Row>");
        }
        sb.Append("</Rows></data>");
```

This is a very quick way to accomplish your task. You are free to standarize the code. Now look at the output which looks same as you need:

```
<data>
<Columns>
    <Column Name="ImageID" />
    <Column Name="ImageName" />
    <Column Name="ImagePath" />
    <Column Name="Width" />
    <Column Name="Height" />
    <Column Name="TileSize" />
    <Column Name="Overlap" />
    <Column Name="MimeType" />
    <Column Name="Scale" />
</Columns>
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <Cell>1</Cell>
        <Cell>untitled.bmp</Cell>
        <Cell>SomePath</Cell>
        <Cell>800</Cell>
        <Cell>190</Cell>
        <Cell>256</Cell>
        <Cell>1</Cell>
        <Cell>image/jpeg</Cell>
        <Cell></Cell>
    </Row>
        <Cell>1</Cell>
        <Cell>untitled.bmp</Cell>
        <Cell>Some Path</Cell>
        <Cell>800</Cell>
        <Cell>190</Cell>
        <Cell>256</Cell>
        <Cell>1</Cell>
        <Cell>image/jpeg</Cell>
        <Cell></Cell>
    </Row>
</Rows>
</data>
```

Note: I have used the same data collection to make two rows of data.

Comment: Thanks for the example, i understood how to form XML dynamically.